# *#9900# not working on LG G3 Beat/Mini

Tags: insufficient-memory, lg

I've just updated to the latest version of Android OS and I keep getting the "Insufficient Memory" error message. It seems there is 4GB allocated to "Misc", which I'm guessing would be fixed by deleting the dump file, but for some reason I can't access the menu via *#9900#. Are there any other methods to doing this?

(I do not keep media files on my phone at all and have already moved many of my apps to my SD card. I've also run CCleaner and cleared all of the major apps' caches)

Comment: While this is a general android code it might not work on your specific phone. Sometimes carriers have their own specific codes, so it might help to list the carrier too.

Comment: I'm on Vodacom (South Africa). I ended up doing a hard reset, but would still like to find a solution, should I run into this problem in the future